# bootstrap slider not showing tooltip on iphone 6, mobile device

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, slider

Hi just found an issue on bootstrap sliders which you can download from https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider 
or 
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

both of these plugins seem to be having the same issue on iphone 6 - the tooltip is not showing up when sliding the slider. I have checked only on iphone 6 but i assume the same issue is for other mobile devices. Has anyone found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known limitation of the bootstrap slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/513). Seiyria suggests setting tooltip to "always", but this will make it visible all the time, not just on slide.

There is a suggested solution in the link above that involves editing the gemfile and initiating the tooltip on touch (instead of slide).